# get does not return the data in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, get, mern

I'm working with a simple GET request but it returns nothing in the browser with no warnings. I checked all the connections to Mongoose works perfectly and collection name are correct.

```
const uriAtlas = "mongodb://localhost:27017/appfullMern";

mongoose.connect(uriAtlas).then(() => 
  console.log("successful connexion DB")
);

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let departSchema = new Schema(
  {
    code: Number,
    name: String,
  },
  { versionKey: false }
);

let Depart = mongoose.model("depart", departSchema);

app.get("/",  (req, res) => {
  Depart.find({}, (err, results) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(results);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the main issue is `mongoose.connect(uriAtlas).then(() => 
  console.log("successful connexion DB")` check error part also
and once your connection is setup then run the server

Comment: Are there any documents (data) in the database for this collection? Where is the code for starting the web server?

Comment: well solved question it turns that  `let Depart = mongoose.model("depart", departSchema);`  will automatically create a table in plural form which means is this case it will create  departs so to avoid this problem we need to add more parameters to it so it will be `let Depart = mongoose.model("depart", departSchema,"depart);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try and wrap the code in a try-catch, but also you're only returning a response if no error. This is bad error handling, as errors or response will bug silently.

```
try { 
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  let departSchema = new Schema(
  {
    code: Number,
    name: String,
  },
  { versionKey: false }
  );
  let Depart = mongoose.model("depart", departSchema);


  app.get("/",  (req, res) => {
    Depart.find({}, (err, results) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(results);
      } else {
        console.log(err)
      }
    });
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: i think the problem is with the data base connection because still no data shown

Comment: console.log("successful connexion DB") is this being returned?

Comment: yes i think the probleme is with the reading from DB

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the request you are making to your app returns with a 200 status. This way you can discard that the problem is with the request per se and not with the response being empty.

Also, consider using async/await syntax instead. Please refactor your code like so and check again:

```
  app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const results = await Depart.find({});
    res.send(results);
  });
```

Comment: tried this and didnt work

Answer (score 0):

well solved question it turns that  `let Depart = mongoose.model("depart", departSchema);`  will automatically create a table in plural form which means is this case it will create  departs so to avoid this problem we need to add more parameters to it so it will be `let Depart = mongoose.model("depart", departSchema,"depart");`